# WooCommerce only show from price on variable products?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I wish to only display the from price on variable products.
But my issue is that when trying to changing it  using this:

```
    function variable_product_only_show_from_price( $price, $from, $to ) {
        return sprintf( '%s: %s', __( 'From', 'text-domain' ), wc_price( $from ) );
    } 
     
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_price_range', 'variable_product_only_show_from_price', 10, 3 );
```

It does nothing and from my testing, it's another function I use that gives me trouble. If I remove the following code, I am able to only show the from price.

```
$user_is_b2b = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(),'b2bking_b2buser', true);

if ($user_is_b2b === 'yes'){
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_suffix', 'add_price_suffix', 99, 4 );
      
    function add_price_suffix( $html, $product, $price, $qty ){
        $html = '<small class="woocommerce-price-suffix"> Ex. moms</small>';
        return $html;
    }
} else {
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_suffix', 'add_price_suffixtwo', 99, 4 );
      
    function add_price_suffixtwo( $html, $product, $price, $qty ){
        $html = '<small class="woocommerce-price-suffix"> Inkl. moms</small>';
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by adding the woocommerce_format_price_range, to before the woocommerce_get_price_suffix